# Interrupt service routine in C++

Tags: c++, delegates, interrupt-handling, isr

For a real time embedded system I'm trying to provide an interrupt handler, which allows for registering *any* non-static method pointer (as well as the object's instance of course), which gets called, when the interrupt occurs.

In C, this was easy to do, e.g.:

```
void (*func)(void*) = 0; // <- method to be called goes here
void* instance;          // <- instance for this-call goes here

void InterruptHandler()
{
  func(instance);
}
```

Afaik, this meets the this-call C++ does implicitly when calling a non-static method.

However, the C++ the compiler refuses to cast a method pointer to a function pointer (at least I found no way to do so) - which surely is comprehensible, but kind of counterproductive in my case.

Is there any way to directly emulate the C++ this-call like in C?
I'm aware of delegates, however my compiler is limited to C++98, no boost library, etc; and even custom lightweight implementations, e.g. Sergey Ryazanov's Impossibly Fast C++ Delegates, provide a certain overhead I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Methods always have a hidden `this` parameter that is probably tripping you up. A lot of useful information and tips here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Answer (score 2):

Methods always contain a hidden `this` parameter to provide access to the object being invoked. To call a class from an interrupt handler that is expecting C or C-like calling behaviour with a 1:1 correspondence between parameters listed and parameters needed, you have to provide that C-like behavior. That means free functions or static methods with no hidden parameters.

And that means you can't assign a method to a function pointer without delving into assumptions about undefined behaviours.

But you can have a static method or free function invoke a method on an object if the object can be made available.

Given

```
void (*func)(void*)
```

Where the `void *` is a pointer to user-provided control information, the simple solution is a static method or free function of the form

```
void handlerCaller(void* userp)
{
    ISRHandlerClass * handlerp = (ISRHandlerClass *) userp;
    handlerp->isrhandler(); // tiny bit may be lost here to subclass look-up
}
```

And

```
void isrhandler()
```

is implemented to do whatever the heck `ISRHandlerClass` or child of `ISRHandlerClass` needs to do.

You are pretty much stuck with `handlerCaller` or something very much like it, so that's overhead you can't avoid. The rest depends on how general you want the ISR interface to be.

A simple generic ISR handler base class:

```
class ISRHandlerClass
{
    public:
        virtual ~ISRHandlerClass()
        {
        }
        // pure virtual to be implemented by specialized handler
        virtual void isrhandler() = 0;  
};
```

and an equally simple implementer

```
class FooHandler: public ISRHandlerClass
{
    public:
        void isrhandler() //override tag if you've got 'em
        {
            // read Foo and store in buffer to be processed by lower priority task
        }  
};
```

But if you want to jettison generalization in favour of speed, don't bother with subclasses. You sacrifice space for multiple handler callers if you need more than one.

```
void FooHandlerCaller(void* userp)
{
    FooHandler * handlerp = (FooHandler *) userp;
    handlerp->isrhandler();
}

void BarHandlerCaller(void* userp)
{
    BarHandler * handlerp = (BarHandler *) userp;
    handlerp->isrhandler();
}
```

Or

```
template <class TYPE>
void handlerCaller(void* userp)
{
    TYPE * handlerp = (TYPE *) userp;
    handlerp->isrhandler();
}
```

usage

```
class FooHandler
{
    public:
        void isrhandler()
        {
            // read Foo and store in buffer to be processed by lower priority task
        }  
};

void (*func)(void*) = handlerCaller<FooHandler>;
FooHandler handler;
void* instance = (void *)&handler;
```